# How to take back control of screenshot functionality from Dropbox?

Tags: screen-capture, dropbox

I have dropbox installed and it forces all screenshots to be saved to a `Screenshots` folder inside the `Dropbox` directory.

I have checked the options that are available when you press `Command + Shift + 5`, but it still says screenshots are being saved to Desktop. This is however in practice not the case.

Dropbox has hijacked the process. How can I take back control, short of uninstalling dropbox, which I do not wish to do?

Comment: This is still a problem and it seems like there is no `import` tab in dropbox preferences anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the `Import` tab in the Dropbox preferences and uncheck "Share screenshots using Dropbox," it fixes this.